# JPA is changing my query and giving me completely wrong results

Tags: jpa

I'm using EntityManager ("em") and creating a query using the method "createQuery", but it changes my query, If I use the method "createNativeQuery" it works fine, but than I can't add a list to parameters.

```
String query = " SELECT t0.id FROM Movie t0, Tagged t1, Tag t2 "
                + " WHERE t2.id = t1.tagfk AND t1.moviefk = t0.id AND t2.name in :tagList  "
                + " GROUP BY t0.id HAVING count(distinct t2.id) = :size "
                + " ORDER BY count(t1) DESC, t0.popularity DESC";

        Query q = em.createQuery(query, Integer.class);
        q.setParameter("tagList", tagList);
        q.setParameter("size", tagList.size());
        q.setMaxResults(20);
        result = (List<Integer>)q.getResultList();
```

The problem here is, when I print the query

```
System.out.println(q);
```

I got

```
SELECT t0.ID AS a1 FROM MOVIE t0, TAG t2, TAGGED t1 WHERE (((t2.ID = t1.TAGFK) AND
(t1.MOVIEFK = t0.ID)) AND (t2.NAME IN ?)) GROUP BY t0.ID 
HAVING (COUNT(DISTINCT(t0.ID)) = ?) ORDER BY COUNT(t1.ID) DESC, t0.POPULARITY DESC       LIMIT ? OFFSET ?"))
```

If you look closer, the:

```
HAVING count(distinct t2.id) = :size
```

became

```
HAVING (COUNT(DISTINCT(t0.ID)) = ?)
```

And obvious I got wrong result, it is checking the wrong table.

Is it a bug or I'm doing something wrong? I can't find why it is happening. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it doing the follow:

First:
Update from JPA 2.0.X to 2.1.X

Second:
In the *HAVING* clause I added the column used in the *SELECT* and *GROUP BY* with a statement that doesn't interfere with anything:

```
HAVING t0.id IS NOT NULL AND count(distinct t2.id) = :size
```

The solution above does not work on 2.0.X, it will result in:

```
HAVING (COUNT(DISTINCT(t0.ID)) = ?) AND (COUNT(DISTINCT(t0.ID)) = ?)
```

weird!!!

I'm using Eclipse Link, I forgot to mention that.

It just works, but still, I'm not happy with the *HAVING* parser on JPA, it needs improvement.